# print on the screen a repeat loop

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a repeating structure in my Java class and wanted to present the data as follows:

```
Peter Black
John Red
```

I do not know if the structure is right, because if I leave to show the color only, the data is overwritten

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] names= {"Peter", "John"};
        String[] colors= {"Black", "Red"};

        for (String name: names) {
            Person d = new Person();

            d.setName(name);

            for (String color: colors) {
                d.setColor(color);
            }
            persons.add(d);
        }

        for (Person a : persons) {
            System.out.println(a.getName() + "-" + a.getColor());
        }
    }
}
```

Console:

```
Peter-Red
John-Red
```

Comment: How are you mapping names to colors? is there any pattern? or it is one to one mapping?

Comment: @DeendayalGarg is 1:1

Comment: @AmandaRJ sorry if I don't understand, but why are you using two string arrays, and not just adding to the list `persons`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a nested for loop, which is not what you are trying to accomplish, loop through both arrays at the same time.

```
if (names.length != colors.length) {
    // error! not a 1:1 relationship
    return;
}
for (int i = 0; i < names.length && i < colors.length; i++) {
    String name = names[i], color = colors[i];
    Person d = new Person();
    d.setName(name);
    d.setColor(color);
    persons.add(d);
}
```

I could just do `i < names.length`, however that will break if both arrays are different sizes, so `i < names.length && i < colors.length` will make sure `i` never exceeds either of the two arrays' lengths.

**Edit:**
I think the real problem here is how you are storing your info. Why are you using two string arrays, instead of a collection containing Person objects?

Answer (score 1):

Stop looping on colors array inside your names loop. A traditional index based loop should help you get the same name and color from each array:

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] names= {"Peter", "John"};
        String[] colors= {"Black", "Red"};

        for (int i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
            Person d = new Person();
            d.setName(names[i]);
            d.setColor(colors[i]);
            persons.add(d);
        }

        for (Person a : persons) {
            System.out.println(a.getName() + "-" + a.getColor());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will break, and throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if the two arrays are different sizes

Comment: That's true. But they aren't. It looks like those begginers practise challenge that considers person features separated in different arrays sharing the same index.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your color loop is INSIDE your name loop.  So for each name you are setting it's color to the first color then the second color and then you are moving on to the next name.

Your biggest problem is probably the use of the advanced for loop, it doesn't give you an index.  If you start with:

```
for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
```

the solution will probably be obvious (and simplify your code)

(I'd give more but it looks like something you are trying to learn with so I'll try to avoid spoilers)

Re your comment--if you wish to simply create only completely filled out objects, use

```
for(int i=0;i<Math.min(names.length, colors.length);i++)
```

If you wish to create partial objects, use Math.max and handle the case inside where either array's length is less than i.  It's all business logic code... define what you want to do and do it.

How to handle bad data (Not part of the original problem):

If you want to handle the cases where the arrays are unequal, if you use the "Math.max" solution above, then adding the inside of the loop could look like this:

```
if(names.length < i)
   d.setName(names[i])
if(colors.length < i)
   d.setColor(colors[i])
```

This way there is no exception and you are safely setting values.

But since that leaves your objects invalid, you might be better off not allowing a different number of colors and names from your user.  If he enters 3 names, then throw away blank colors and keep re-prompting until you have 3 colors--then stop prompting.  It's always safest to catch problems like this as soon as possible.

Another good solution, start with:

```
if(names.length != colors.length)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("createUsers method must have the same number of names as colors but was called with "+names.length+" names and "+colors.length+" colors")
```

Ensuring your parameters are correct and throwing an exception if they are not simplifies your code a LOT and is generally a very good practice.

Comment: same problem as Rafael's answer above

Comment: By the way you are coding they MUST be the same size.  If you need to handle arrays of different sizes then you must define what you wish to do in that case and write exception code for it.  (If the second array is shorter, does the test throw out or does Person get an invalid color?  If color is longer does the code throw out, do you throw away the last values, or do you create a person without a name.  These exceptions have to be considered regardless of your solution and you didn't really address them in your example.

Comment: Yes I understand, however what if the user gives this info?

Comment: You still have to define how  you want to handle it.  You can re-prompt the user, you can create partial objects, you can skip some objects that would have been partial, or you can throw an exception.   Which do you want to do?

Comment: true, I guess the real problem is that we don't catch the exception

Comment: It doesn't have to be an exception.  I'll modify the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Enum like

```
enum Entity {
        Peter("Black"),
        John("Red");

        private final String color;

        Entity(String color) {
            this.color = color;
        }
```

Comment: If you were to use an enum, I would change Person to an interface and make the enum implement Person

Comment: Yeah, it will be a better design.

Comment: @Ankushsoni  I can not. This test was for me to include the data in my database. I have a form and the data comes from it . I get form a list of strings .